# Focusing a Bootstrap button for keyboard enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, marionette

I have a Bootstrap 3.0 button on a web page.  The button is not part of a form.  When this page renders, I would like for the button to be clicked if the user hits return on the keyboard.  I have a Marionette event listener set up to handle the click event.

Here is my button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary js-new pull-right">New facility</button>
```

How do I do this?

I have tried several things - including what I thought was the obvious solution: executing `$(".js-new").first().focus()`.  This does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to trigger the click handler for a certain button when "return" is hit. If that's the case, this ought to work; `$(".js-new").first().click();`, assuming your selector is correct.

You can check whether or not your selector is finding an element by using either `alert` or `console.log` to display the length of the selector: `console.log($(".js-new").length);`.

Once you have verified that you have found the correct element, you can trigger whatever click handler(s) are bound to the element by simply calling the `.click()` function; if no arguments are passed to it, it executes whatever triggers are already on the element.

--

Edit: if you'd simply like to trigger the click handler when enter is pressed, you could bind an event to the return key:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13) {
        // enter has been pressed, execute a click on .js-new:
        $(".js-new").first().click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure OP means that the button would be selected (= focused) when entering the site so that pressing "enter" would click the button automatically, in which case the code he has should work.

Comment: Ah. Well, that's not necessary; I'll include a solution for that that would be more dependable.

Comment: @Ellit your solution works -- thanks.  I wish I understood why my .focus() approach does not.  Best!

Comment: While it is not the best approach, it should work, see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sfxcp/. Most likely you are not calling the .focus() after after document.ready (for instance $(document).ready(function(){$(.js-new).first().focus()}) or something else is stealing the focus, which you can test with console.log($(".js-new").first().is(":focus"))

Comment: @PeteTNT something probably like that, but this is a single page app, so the button is there.  Probably the focus steal thing -- which I will have to look at closer.  Thanks!